# How to set color dashed vertical rule between images

Tags: graphics, captions, subcaption

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphics}
 \usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\rulesep}{\color{blue} \unskip\ \vrule\ }    \begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
\end{subfigure}
\rulesep
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{set vertical dashed rule between image ?}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

here the code of adding [vertical rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159290/how-can-i-place-a-vertical-rule-between-subfigures). I changed the color, but I need to change also the style and thickness.

[image]

Comment: It should be `\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip{\color{blue}\ \vrule\ }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With array, arydshln and colortbl :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, colortbl}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphics}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\newcommand{\rulesep}{\color{blue} \unskip\ \vrule\ }    \begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
\begin{tabular}{>{\arrayrulecolor{blue}}c:c}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
\end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}
\caption{set vertical dashed rule between image ?}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we change the thickness of the rule ?

Comment: \arrayrulewidth=2pt (by default, 0.4pt)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe.png}
    \end{subfigure} & \tikz{\draw[-,blue, densely dashed, thick](0,-1.05) -- (0,1.05);} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe.png}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}   
\caption{set vertical dashed rule between image ?}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, in this version one has to know the height of the png pictures. I was unable to compute the height of these in LaTeX. '