# Adding a dashed vertical line between subfigures and their subcaptions

Tags: subcaption

Similar to this:
[How to set color dashed vertical rule between images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405921/how-to-set-color-dashed-vertical-rule-between-images)

I want to place a dashed line between two subfigures. I have been able to get it working with a \vrule, but anything I do with the dashed lines stops at the base of the figures rather than extending through the subcaptions. I am using the subcaption package for the figures.

Here is the code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{This is the first subcaption
        \label{fig:solid1}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \hspace{2pt}
    \unskip\vrule
    \hspace{2pt}
    \subcaptionbox{Get your second subcaptions here
        \label{fig:solid2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{This separator has the right height, but isn't dashed.}
    \label{fig:solid}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\testBox{\subcaptionbox{This is the first subcaption
            \label{fig:dash1}}
        {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}}
    \newlength\figHeight
    \setlength\figHeight{\heightof{\testBox}}
    \testBox
    \hspace{3pt}
    \tikz{\draw[densely dashed, thick](0,\figHeight) -- (0,0);}
    \hspace{1pt}
    \subcaptionbox{Get your second subcaptions here
        \label{fig:dash2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{This separator is dashed, but is too short.}
    \label{fig:dashes}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Also, why do I need to have different \hspace distances to center the dashed line?
[image: figure 1 result]

[image: figure 2 result]

Comment: Why not use a light-coloured `\vrule` instead of a solid, dashed rule?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code to make it something we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done! Just forgot to copy over the package includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nicematrix` package to encapsulate the `subtitle boxes` in tabular form,  and then use the `\Block` command to draw the dashed rule.

`\Block[borders={right,tikz=dashed}]{1-1}{}` will draw the dashed rule only on the right side of the first node.

Requires the Tikz package to be loaded. I will compile it twice.

[image: C]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{nicematrix}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering 
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
        \Block[borders={right,tikz={densely dashed, thick}}]{1-1}{}%draw the dashed rule only on the right side of the first node
        \subcaptionbox{This is the first subcaption \label{fig:solid1}} {\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-b}}&
        \subcaptionbox{Get your second subcaptions here \label{fig:solid2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{NiceTabular}   
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great and is much simpler than trying to capture and measure components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arydshln`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} c : c @{}}
  \subcaptionbox{This is the first subcaption\label{fig:solid1}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
&
  \subcaptionbox{Get your second subcaptions here\label{fig:solid2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{tabular}

\caption{This separator has the right height, but isn't dashed.}
\label{fig:solid}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I can't see how this improves the typesetting, though.

[image]